# AVL tree with strings error: Access violation reading location 0x72746E69 when searching/comparing using C++ in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, avl-tree

This is a program I am writing for a class. In the program we are to read from 20 different files and insert individual words into an AVL tree. The algorithms we use (from IndexType.cpp) are given to us by the professor and we are told not to modify them.

My problem is this, when searching(The function named Find)/inserting (happens in both of them) I get the error Access violation reading location 0x72746E69. This error always appears around the halfway point when reading from the 7th file.

I have tried moving around return statements and restructering the code entirely but nothing seems to solve the problem. Any help in figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Relevant code is as follows:

Main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include "indexType.h"
#include "occurrenceType.h"

using namespace std;

string filenameConverter(string& filename);

IndexType InputToIndex(IndexType& index);

int main()
{
    IndexType index;
    OccurrenceType idk;

    index = InputToIndex(index);

    index.InOrder(); //not relevant to my problem

    return 0;
}

IndexType InputToIndex(IndexType& index)
{
    int page;
    const int filemax = 21;

    ifstream* in;
    in = new ifstream[filemax];
    string filename;

    indexEntry entry;
    string word;

    occurrenceLocation save;

    page = 1;
    filename = "1.txt";
    in[page].open(filename);
    int position_counter = 0;

    while (page < 21)
    {
        while (in[page])
        {
            in[page] >> word;
            transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
            cout << word << " " << page << endl;
            position_counter++;

            index.Find(word);
            if (!index.IsPSet())
            {
                cout << "jep" << endl;
                entry.word = word;
                save.page = page;
                save.position = position_counter;
                entry.occurrences.Write(save);

                if (!index.IsFull())
                {
                        index.Insert(entry);
                        if (!index.IsPSet())
                        {
                            exit(1);
                        }
                }
            }
            else if (index.IsPSet())
            {
                save.page = page;
                save.position = position_counter;

                if (index.IsPSet())
                {
                    index.Write(save);
                }
            }
        }

        in[page].clear();

        if (filename == "20.txt")
        {
            return index;
        }
//filenameConverter changes the variable filename to the next file to read
        filename = filenameConverter(filename);

        position_counter = 0;
        page++;
        in[page].open(filename);
    }
    return index;
}
```

IndexType.cpp (I have only included the relevant functions where the problem exists)

```
void IndexType::Find(string x, IndexNode*& q)
{
    // assumes q is passed-by-value
    // sets p
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        p = q;
        return;
    }
    else if (q != NULL && x.compare(q->entry.word) == 0) //spot where the error occurs
    {
        p = q;
        return;
    }
    else if (x.compare(q->entry.word) < 0)
    {
        Find(x, q->left);
    }
    else if (x.compare(q->entry.word) > 0)
    {
        Find(x, q->right);
    }
}

void IndexType::Insert(indexEntry x, IndexNode*& q)
{
    // assumes q is passed-by-reference
    // always call IsFull prior to calling Insert
    // always call IsPSet after calling Insert
    // sets p
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        q = new IndexNode;
        q->entry.word = x.word;
        q->left = NULL;
        q->right = NULL;
        p = q;
        return;
    }
    else if (x.word.compare(q->entry.word) < 0) //spot where the error occurs
    {
        Insert(x, q->left);
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            if (Height(q->left) - Height(q->right) == 2)
            {
                if (x.word.compare(q->left->entry.word) < 0)
                    LL(q);
                else if(x.word.compare(q->left->entry.word) > 0)
                    LR(q);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (x.word.compare(q->entry.word) > 0)
    {
        Insert(x, q->right);
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            if (Height(q->right) - Height(q->left) == 2)
            {
                if (x.word.compare(q->right->entry.word) > 0)
                    RR(q);
                else if(x.word.compare(q->right->entry.word) < 0)
                    RL(q);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(x.word.compare(q->entry.word) == 0)
    {
        exit(1);
        p = NULL; // assumes duplicates are not allowed
    }
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        q->height = max(Height(q->left), Height(q->right)) + 1;
        q->entry.occurrences.Write(x.occurrences.Read());
    }
    return;
}
```

It is my first time using this to ask for help so if you need any further information just ask. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: You have to use a debugger.

Comment: `in = new ifstream[filemax];` ?? You are only reading for a single stream at a trime. You don't need an array of streams. Do you just not like the first index '0'? `page = 1;` and then `in[page]` ignores `in[0]`. If you then use indexes `1 + 20 = 21` then `in[21]` is outside of the bounds you provide.

Comment: I was using that because I was having trouble with the while(in[page]) loop.  I have changed it to use in now and it seems the problem I was having was that I was not closing the file after using it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Also I have used the debugger that is how I know what lines the problem is on I just don't know exactly what the error means or how to fix it. Sorry about being unclear.